# Angular migration from 8.1.13 to 9.1 .problem in custom library

Tags: angular, typescript, migration, angular-library, angular-ivy

i have some components which was working before

while going through  the migration i'am facing this

so while doing the following command `ng update @angular/core --migrate-only migration-v9-undecorated-classes-with-di`

> This migration uses the Angular compiler internally and therefore
> projects that no longer build successfully after the update cannot run
> the migration. Please ensure there are no AOT compilation errors and
> rerun the migration. The following project failed:
> src/tsconfig.app.json

```
    Error: error TS100: Cannot determine the module for class StoveDirective in 
/Users/aby/Projects/components/src/lib/ui-core/stove/stove.directive.ts! Add StoveDirective to the NgModule to fix it.
```

i have a sub module where i have imported to the **declaration** and **exports** then added the sub module to ngModule file

any pointers will be great !!!

this is the sub module where i have declared the directive

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    stoveDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    stoveDirective
  ],
  providers: [ ]
})
export class subModule {

}
```

this is the main  module where i have importing the sub module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    subModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    subModule,
  ]
})
export class MainModule { }
```

and added the link to the **public_api.ts**

```
export * from '.lib/ui-core/stove/stove.directive';
```

since it is a custom package there  ivy should be disabled [link](https://angular.io/guide/ivy#maintaining-library-compatibility)

Comment: Please show us some code where did you declared the `directive` and show us the modules.
I dont know how to help you with this error if I dont see how did you declared and imported.

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi i have added all the  code and changes

Comment: Even I have a similar problem